# Haskell module imports itself

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I have src/Main.hs define the `Main` module and tests/Tests.hs import the `Main` module. Why does `cabal build` tell me `module 'Main' (tests/Tests.hs) imports itself`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you give `Tests` a module header?

```
module Tests where

import Main

-- ...
```

Also, depending on the testing framework, test suites are usually run as a standalone executable with their own `main`, importing common modules that `Main` also uses.

Comment: This solved my problem, but can someone explain to my why this produces the error `module 'Main' imports itself`?

Comment: @Niek: The default module name if you don’t specify one is `Main`, so in this example it’s as if the file contained `module Main where { import Main }`, and the `Main` in the import is assumed to refer to the current module. If they’re from different packages, like `my-package` and `my-package-tests`, you can disambiguate the import using the `PackageImports` language flag, e.g. `{-# Language PackageImports #-}` plus `import "my-package" Main`. But it’s better to just give them more distinctive names, or put imported code in a “library” module and have `Main` just be the entry point.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and changing the name of the module Main to something else fixed it. May be Main has a particular meaning for haskell...

Comment: `Main` is the default module name if there is no module header.